# Jenkins Pipeline: How do I catch an error in stage x, but skip the next stage (y), but still run the last stage (z) after that?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, try-catch, jenkins-groovy

In a Declarative Pipeline, I know I can try/catch an error in a stage and run the remaining stages of the pipeline. But what if I want to skip all next stages in case of failure, except the last stage - that one I want to run!

```
script {
  try {
      sh 'do your stuff'
  } catch (Exception e) {
      echo 'Exception occurred: ' + e.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [when expressions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) for this. Example below.

```
def skipStages = false

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Hello 1'
                        try {
                            error "Something"
                        } catch(e) {
                            skipStages = true
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        stage('2') {
            when { expression { !skipStages } }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Hello 222222'
                }
                    
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            when { expression { !skipStages } }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Hello 3333'
                }
                    
            }
        }
        stage('Last') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Hello Last'
                }
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```